# How to config or modify Drupal to completely remove Drupal's login, even for the admin?

Tags: drupal, authentication

Here is the background.

I need to have the SAME Drupal website deployed on two servers. The first is for the internet access and we don't want to have any Drupal login for it, not even for admin.

The second server is on our organization's internal network and the Drupal website on this server is just regular one.

What is the elegant way to config/modify Drupal on the first server?

For me, it is acceptable that for the internet Drupal, a link such as http://myorg.com/user still works, but there should be no form for it. If I want to do this, which files do I need to modify and how?

Another solution might be without any config/modification of Drupal, the first server can have a redirect and any http://myorg.com/user will be redirected to another page. Is this doable? How?

I am using Drupal 7 and the server environment is Unix.

Thanks a lot for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to what Bright Plum suggested is that you can modify the .htaccess. To disallow all the /admin paths and /user paths.

But the way answered by Bright Plum may be a little bit better. Because it allows you to have the same code on both servers (with different database) in the first one you enable your module and on the second one you never enable it).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Bright and Miguel, thank you both very much. I forgot to mention that the two websites share the same database. I tested and feel that .htaccess approach is quite elegant. 
Bright: I learned a bit from you reply.

Answer (score 1):

Any path within Drupal is alterable via [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7).

Simple create your custom module, use the hook, and set the paths you want (user, user/login) to deny access.

You can set the configuration for users to disallow registration to disable user/register.

The items are an array, so you can simply add a property 'access callback' and set it to FALSE.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  //disable the user login paths
  $items['user']['access callback'] = FALSE;
  $items['user/login']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```